# Sieve of Sundaram is not removing all numbers

Tags: python, nested-loops

I am working on a Python homework that asks me to code the Sieve of Sundaram:

*- start with a list of numbers from 1 to n;

- for every pair of integers i and j where 1<= i <= j and i + j + 2ij <= n, remove i + j + 2ij from - the list above;
- finally, for each remaining number k in the list, 2k+1 is a prime number.*

This is my code:

```
n = int(input())
num_lst = list(range(1, n + 1))

for i in num_lst:
    for j in num_lst:
        if (1 <= i <= j) and (i + j + (2 * i * j)) <= n:
            num_lst.remove((i + j + (2 * i * j)))
    
print(num_lst)

for idx, k in enumerate(num_lst):
    num_lst[idx] = 2 * k + 1

print(num_lst)
```

I see many solutions that uses list comprehensions, but at this point of the class, we have not covered it yet.

When input is 50, I'm getting prime numbers up until 101; but I'm also getting some that are not primes (27, 45, 63, 99).
What did I do wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Strange result when removing item from a list while iterating over it in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260089/strange-result-when-removing-item-from-a-list-while-iterating-over-it-in-python)

Comment: Don't add/remove items from a list as you're iterating over it.  The loop iterator gets out of synch with the actual loop contents, and weird things happen.

Comment: Hey John, how would you go about doing that? I tried making a copy of the list, but I wasn't sure that I'm doing is right.

Comment: The usual approach is not to actually remove items from the original list at all, but instead build a new list with only the items that you want to keep.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tried this:

```
n = int(input())
num_lst = list(range(1, n + 1))
to_remove = set()

for i in num_lst:
    for j in num_lst:
        if 1 <= i <= j and i + j + 2 * i * j <= n:
            to_remove.add(i + j + 2 * i * j)

# Remove elements from num_lst after the nested loops
for num in to_remove:
    if num in num_lst:
        num_lst.remove(num)

print(num_lst)

for idx, k in enumerate(num_lst):
    num_lst[idx] = 2 * k + 1

print(num_lst)
```

OUTPUT:

```
50
[1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9, 11, 14, 15, 18, 20, 21, 23, 26, 29, 30, 33, 35, 36, 39, 41, 44, 48, 50]
[3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97, 101]
```